# Auto orienting images with Carrierwave causes them to not save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, carrierwave

Using Rails 3.2.13 and Carrierwave 0.9.0, and I noticed my images were all rotated when uploading, so I wanted to auto orient them. This is the uploader:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  process :auto_orient
  storage :fog

  def auto_orient
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.auto_orient
      img
    end
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

After adding the process line, images will no longer save to the database. They save fine if I comment out that line. The form I'm using allows for multiple photo uploads at once and has photos_attributes nested under the photo album resource, as they're getting created together. This is the Photo model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :photo ...
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  belongs_to :album
end
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: What happens when you try to create a single photo at the rails console? What if you add `validates_processing_of :photo` to your model and check the errors?

Comment: From the console, when calling photo.save! I get the error Photo Failed to manipulate with rmagick, maybe it is not an image?   Original Error: unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.7-0/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/jpeg.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1276

Comment: Problem solved, posting below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It seemed that jpeg wasn't installed, so I ran

```
brew install jpeg
```

which told me that it was already installed, just not linked, so I ran

```
brew link jpeg
```

which said that there was an existing link, so I ran

```
brew link --overwrite jpeg
```

That solved the problem.